# Segue animation doesn't align screen correctly

Tags: ios, autolayout, segue

This is how it should look like, with filling the screen fully:

[image]

And this is how it looks when I transition via a a segue that's set to present modally and I am using a custom animation([http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/](http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/vid03.gif)):

[image]

Comment: Could you post your animation code? Also are you using storyboards?

Comment: yes, I'm using storyboards and auto-layout and size classes. Actually my animation doesn't even get called for some reason. I followed this tutorial:
http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/